# JavaScript adding total input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calculator that adds a 15 percent to an input value, triples that value and finally adds 7.25 percent. Then it appends that value into a new div. The last step I need is to add up the values from the inputs submitted and have that displayed onto the "total-price" div. I tried adding the prices but these show up as NaN. How can I solve this ? Thanks.

In other words.. See the empty white div, under Total?..at the very bottom.. Well I'd like to add the submitted prices accordingly and display a total price inside that div.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <title>NC Tax Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="calculator-container">
    <h1>NC Tax Calculator</h1>
    <form id="form" name="form" action="" >
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price-holder" maxlength="10" size="10">
    </form>
   <button type="button" id="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" id="reset" class="button">Reset</button>
   <div class="final-price-container"></div>
   <p>This app adds 15% to the wholesale price (Shipping Charge), then triples the price for retail and adds 7.25% (North Carolina tax).</p>
    <h2>Total</h2>
    <div id="total-price"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#calculator-container { 
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 2%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
  .button {
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin: 0 8px;
  font-size: 18px; 
}
#price-holder {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}
#price-added {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
#submit {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#reset {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
#calculator-container h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.final-price-container {
  margin: 16px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
#calculator-container p {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}
#total-price {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

// step 1. Enter a number into input
  // When submit button is clicked
  // Add the final price into the body div
// step 2. Display an alert button 
  // if input value is NaN display alert
  // else continue with calculation
// step 3. Calculate price 
  // add 15% to the original number 
  // triples the original number 
  // then multiplies by 7.25% for tax 
// step 4. Add reset button 
  // when clicked, it clears the div 

// global variables
var price;
var wholeSalePrice;
var submitButton = $("#submit");
var resetButton = $("#reset");


// function when submit button is clicked
submitButton.click(function() {
    //adds input value to wholeSalePrice variable and appends to div 

    wholeSalePrice = parseFloat($("#price-holder").val());
    if ( isNaN(wholeSalePrice) ) {
        alert("Please enter a number");
    } 
    else {
        priceCalculate();
        $(".final-price-container").append("<div id='price-added'>" + price + "</div>");
        console.log("whole sale price is " + wholeSalePrice);
        console.log("final price is " + price);
    };
});

//function for calculating the final price 
function priceCalculate() {
    // adds 15% to wholesale price. 
    price = wholeSalePrice + (wholeSalePrice * 0.15);
    // triples the new price.
    price = price * 3; 
    // multiply price by 7.25% to add tax.
    price = (price * 0.0725) + price;
    // set price to two decimal places.
    price = price.toFixed(2);
    return price;       
}; 

// function for reseting 
resetButton.click(function() {
    $("#price-added").remove();
  });
});

//Total price display
```

Comment: hey @FNunez, you don't need to post all of this lines of code, post the minimum amount of code need it so people can understand and reproduce the problem easily. This will also help you understand the issue better.

Comment: Seems to work for me? I don't get NaN. http://jsfiddle.net/33reg0p3/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to get the sum of all calculated results you got via "submit" and add this to the "Total" div?

If yes, then you can find a working solution for your example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nhfka1ee/

The only thing i added is this:

```
    $(".final-price-container").append("<div class='price'>" + price + "</div>");

    var totalPrice = 0;
    $('.final-price-container .price').each(function(){
        totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $('#total-price').html(totalPrice);
```

**EDIT**

In order to keep the reset button working, you'll have to change the according function to something like this: (because i changed the multiple new divs with ids to the class .price)

```
resetButton.click(function() {
    $(".final-price-container .price").remove();
    $('#total-price').html('');
  });
});
```

I updated the fiddle to reflect this change: https://jsfiddle.net/nhfka1ee/1/

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work but it broke the reset button.

Comment: I updated my answer with the information about how to keep the reset buttons functionality.